# How does BGProcessingTask works?

Tags: swift, ios13, ios-background-mode

I'm trying to understand the the specifics of the background work in iOS 13.

Will the BGProcessingTask be done if the user did not enter the application for a week or or will it never be fulfilled if a week has passed ?

Apple says that BGProcessingTask will be able to run for several minutes - how many minutes are we talking about?

Apple documentation does not answer these questions yet. The answers can be obtained experimentally, but I have not tried not to use the application for a week for background checks.

Comment: It depends upon the type of background task you are scheduling. Are you talking about background fetch? The frequency is dictated by how often the user uses the app, but Apple has never (AFAIK) specifically outlined the precise rules, and they’re subject to change from one iOS release to another. If you’re not talking about background fetch, perhaps you can clarify precisely what your tasks are doing...